# Jquery.load(html) not working

Tags: jquery

my JSfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/VAAKf/3/

When i click on search, it doesn't do anything, but when i put alert, I get alert.

Please let me know what might be going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: your `search.html` is located in the same folder as the caller file, right?

Comment: I would wager a lack of search.html on JSfiddle, I get an error in the error console when I click it: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: but it is not doing anything on my page :(

Comment: seems like not even alert is working, even though jquery is included on the page

Comment: check the path to your jQuery, check the search file extension (maybe it's `search.htm`), delete everything from it and put just a `hello world` string

Comment: path to jQuery is correct and file name and path is also right

Comment: so how comes even the alert doesn't work? Any other library included on the page that uses `$` ?

Comment: I see from firebug that jQuery source is attached, I believe that is not the problem that, so it should still alert, but it isn't :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two jquery functions, when I made this jQuery function at top, the alert started to work

```
// loading search page
$(function(){
    $("#search").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
    });
});

// animating slideshow on landing page
$(function(){
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        pagination: true,
        preloadImage: '../static/img/loading.gif',
        play: 2000,
        pause: 1000,
        hoverPause: true
    });

    $('.slides_control').css({
        "height": "600px",
        "margin-right": "400px"
    });

    $('.pagination').hide('')
});
```

How did that work?  I have no idea. Do i need to order the calls?